# Format of Date Time Picker

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, datetimepicker, regional-settings

```
dtpPurDate.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
dtpPurDate.Text = DT.Rows(i)("PurDate")
```

In Access, PurDate is 1/1/1900 but in date time picker it's shown as 01-01-2000. At this time, short date format of system regional setting is like

[image: short date format]

If it's d/M/yyyy, it's shown as 01-01-1900.

How should I set the date time picker whatever regional setting is?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the custom format string `dd-MM-yyyy`. With this custom format string, the `-` character is treated as a literal, and copied to the result string unchanged. Thus, all of your dates will use `-` as the date separator, regardless of your environment's regional settings.

Instead, you want to replace the literal `-` with the magic `/`. This is [a special value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) that indicates to the control you want to use the appropriate localized date separator, as retrieved from the [`DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) of the current culture.

So your custom format string should be re-written as: `dd/MM/yyyy`.